# Ios 13 location permission ask next time dosen't work in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location, ios13

`iOS 12` completely work location permission But in  `iOS 13` location permission ask next time issue in `Swift 3`.

I request for `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in `iOS 12` and the user selects always.

Now the user update to `iOS 13`.

whenever change the status in setting go App Location permission and check `"While Using the App"` and go back and it's automatically status change to provisional mode, or it will stay in " ask next time " mode?

Thanks

Comment: did you just say on iOS 13 in Swift 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575516/ios13-provisional-location-permission